# Genitiv in einem Relativsatz: Ist der Satz grammatikalisch richtig?

Tags: genitive, relative-clause

Ich möchte diesen Satz in einer Bewebung benutzen und frage mich ob es richtig ist:

> Es ist eine anspruchsvolle Aufgabe, deren Herausforderung ich mir bewusst bin und auf die ich mich freue.

Danke!

Answer (score 2):

Der Satz hinkt, gar nicht eigentlich wegen des Genitivs, sondern weil du "Herausforderung" nicht in dieser Weise auf "Aufgabe" beziehen kannst. (Kurz: Die Aufgabe **ist** die Herausforderung, sie **hat** keine. Dies jedenfalls nach dem bisher üblichen Sprachgebrauch.)

Wohlgeformt wären zum Beispiel folgende Sätze:

> Es ist eine anspruchsvolle Aufgabe, deren Schwierigkeit mir bewusst ist und auf die ich  mich freue.
>
> Es ist eine anspruchsvolle Aufgabe, deren Schwierigkeit ich mir bewusst bin und auf die ich mich freue.
>
> Es ist eine anspruchsvolle Aufgabe, über deren Schwierigkeit ich mir im Klaren bin und auf die ich mich freue.
>
> Es ist eine anspruchsvolle Aufgabe. Ich freue mich auf die Herausforderung, sie anzugehen.

Das zweite Beispiel ("eine Aufgabe, deren Schwierigkeit ich mir bewusst bin") hat ein weiteres Problem: Irgendwie klingt es - für meinen Geschmack - komisch. Der Grund ist, meine ich nach längerem Grübeln, dass der Genitiv ("deren Schwierigkeit") hier in zwei unterschiedlichen Funktionen gleichzeitig verwendet wird. Erstens als Genitiv, der die Zugehörigkeit der Schwierigkeit zur Aufgabe darstellt (die Schwierigkeit der Aufgabe). Zweitens als Genitiv für das Objekt des "sich einer Sache bewusst seins". Wegen dieser doppelten Beanspruchung des Genitivs hat man (oder jedenfalls ich) das Gefühl, dass da irgendetwas fehlt. Rein satzbautechnisch ist der Satz jedoch korrekt.

---

(Klammer auf:

Sprachlich korrekt, stilistisch aber wohl etwas zu mäandernd könntest du auch sagen:

> Es ist eine anspruchsvolle Aufgabe, deren Charakter als Herausforderung mir bewusst ist und auf die ich mich freue.

Das geht, weil eine Aufgabe einen Charakter ***haben*** kann, aber keine Herausforderung. Wie gesagt, eine Aufgabe kann eine Herausforderung ***sein*** oder ***darstellen***.

Klammer zu)

Comment: Vielen Dank für die detaillierte Antwort! Ich werde den 4. Satz anwenden. Es ist fließend und weniger kompliziert. Danke!!!

Comment: Gute Wahl! - Viel Erfolg bei der Bewerbung!